# AWS Aurora RDS PostgreSql create global database for existing cluster through cloud formation script

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-aurora

We already have a cluster and instance of Aurora PostgreSql in abc region.  Now as part of disaster recovery strategy, we are trying to create a read replica in a xyz region.

I was able to create it manually by clicking on "Add Region" in AWS web console.  [As explained here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-global-database.html#aurora-global-database-creating).

As part of it, following as been created. 
1. A global database to the existing cluster 
2. Secondary region cluster
3. Secondary region instance.

Everything is fine.  Now I have to implement this through cloud formation script.

My first question is, can we do this through Cloud formation script without losing data if primary cluster and instance already created ?

If possible, please share aws doc for cloud formation scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the other post on this subject: [CloudFormation templates for Global Aurora Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55928299/cloudformation-templates-for-global-aurora-database)

The API that is required for setting up the GlobalCluster is AWS::RDS::GlobalCluster and this is currently not listed in [CloudFormation documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_RDS.html).

I was able to do the same using Terraform and that is documented for PostgreSQL here: [Getting Aurora PostgreSQL Global Database setup using Terraform](https://medium.com/@aga_sumit/getting-aurora-postgresql-global-database-setup-using-terraform-afa0cd9f85bd?source=friends_link&sk=d0a9ce88802573f97ba2034e06390a62)